# Titanium - Error: write EPIPE compiling iOS app

Tags: node.js, titanium-mobile, appcelerator-mobile

I'm compiling my iOS app for distribution via command-line and this error appear:

```
[DEBUG] Running /Users/a/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/5.0.2.GA/iphone/titanium_prep "com.lalala" "/Users/a/Documents/Titanium_Studio_Workspace/Prueba_Alloy/build/iphone/assets"
Error: write EPIPE
at errnoException (net.js:905:11)
at Object.afterWrite (net.js:721:19)
```

And this error:

```
Error: write EPIPE
    at Object.exports._errnoException (util.js:874:11)
    at exports._exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:897:20)
    at WriteWrap.afterWrite (net.js:763:14)
```

> > Operating System   Name                        = Mac OS X    Version   = 10.11   Architecture                = 64bit
> >     CPUs                      = 8    Memory                      = 4294967296
> >
> > Node.js    Node.js Version             = 4.2.1    npm Version           = 2.14.7
> >
> > Titanium CLI    CLI Version                 = 5.0.5
> >
> > Titanium SDK    SDK Version                 = 5.0.2.GA

What is the problem? I don't underestand what this error means. I need a solution fast.
Thank you for advance.

My [question](https://community.appcelerator.com/topic/3768/error-error-write-epipe-compiling-ios-app) in Appcelerator Community Q&A.

THIS ONLY HAPPEN ON iOS

**EDIT:**

With node v0.12:

```
 Error: write EPIPE
     at exports._errnoException (util.js:746:11)
     at WriteWrap.afterWrite (net.js:775:14)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution has been downgrading node to v0.10.7, this version hasn't got the error.